# Swift / popViewControllerAnimated throws nil / how to go back to previous viewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a `UIViewController` inside a `UIPageViewController`. The `UIPageViewController` is embedded into a `UINavigatonController`.

I'm calling a second UIViewController by:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

`vc` has a `UINavigationBar` (by InterfaceBuilder) with a leftButton item. Once this button is pressed, I want to go back to the 1st viewController by:

```
@IBAction func backBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

This throws me lldb. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

PS: the NavigationBar of the `UINavigatonController` is hidden within the whole project. I want each called VCs to have their own NavigationBar.

PPS: I've checked like a billion times. The buttons outlets/actions are correctly set.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the action on the Button. I deleted the action. Created a new action by clicking and dragging. Copy/pasted my Code and then it worked.

[image]

The only difference I can tell was, that before it said: `backBtnWithSender:` and now just `backButton` (without the `AndSender` additional).

I believe the problem occurred because I copy/pasted the button function and wired it to the NavigationBar Button manually. After creaating a "new" function this problem was gone.